# Creating a ViewModel for IEnumerable<SelectListItem> allSundaysInMonth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

ViewModel for allSundaysInMonth, I kept this the same:

```
  namespace TradeUK.Admin.Web.ViewModels
  {
      public class SundaysInMonthViewModel
      {
         public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllSundays { set; get; }
         public string SelectedSunday { set; get; }
      }
  }
```

Then in my action the new code:

```
public ActionResult TradeUKKPISearchesData() //show dropdownlist in the view
{
  var now = DateTime.Now;
  var lastMonth = now.AddMonths(-1);
  var lastMonthSundays = GetDatesOfSundays(lastMonth.Year, lastMonth.Month);
  var thisMonthSundays = GetDatesOfSundays(now.Year, now.Month);
  var sundaysToTakeFromLastMonth = 2;
  var sundays = lastMonthSundays.Skip(Math.Max(0, lastMonthSundays.Count() - sundaysToTakeFromLastMonth)).Take(sundaysToTakeFromLastMonth).Concat(thisMonthSundays);

  var allSundaysInThisMonth = new SundaysInMonthViewModel
  {
    AllSundays = sundays.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
      Value = x.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
      Text = x.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
    });

    //or must I have the code here? not sure how all this works yet
    SelectedSunday = sundays.Select(y => new SelectListItem
    {
      Value = 
      Text = 
    }) 
  };

  //this is what I meant or can I add this to the above?
  var selectedSunday = new SundaysInMonthViewModel{
    SelectedSunday = sundays.Select(y => new SelectListItem
    {
      Value = 
    })
  }
  return View(allSundaysInThisMonth);
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDatesOfSundays(int year, int month)
{
    var ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    for (int i = 1; i <= ci.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, month); i++)
    {
        var date = new DateTime(year, month, i);
        if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            yield return date;
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult TradeUKKPISearchesData()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var lastMonth = now.AddMonths(-1);
    var lastMonthSundays = GetDatesOfSundays(lastMonth.Year, lastMonth.Month);
    var thisMonthSundays = GetDatesOfSundays(now.Year, now.Month);
    var sundaysToTakeFromLastMonth = 2;
    var sundays = lastMonthSundays
        .Skip(Math.Max(0, lastMonthSundays.Count() - sundaysToTakeFromLastMonth))
        .Take(sundaysToTakeFromLastMonth)
        .Concat(thisMonthSundays);

    var allSundaysInThisMonth = new SundaysInMonthViewModel
    {
        AllSundays = sundays.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            // TODO: Adjust the formats you want for the 
            // Value and Text of your ddl
            Value = x.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
            Text = x.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        }),
        SelectedSunday = thisMonthSundays
            .Where(x => x < now)
            .Last()
            .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    };
    return View(allSundaysInThisMonth);
}
```

and in your view:

```
@model SundaysInMonthViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedSunday, Model.AllSundays)
```

Comment: thank you I will work through this and try and understand. Just one thing: I have the System.Globalization namespace but the InvariantCulture part of CultureInfo is not recognized?

Comment: I don't know, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is well there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx Works fine for me.

Comment: the code is ok I made a typo my bad, I ran the code but get an error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TradeUK.Admin.Web.ViewModels.SundaysInMonthViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Int32]]' ? My type in the viewmodel is IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllSundays and string?

Comment: @charlie_cat, did you read my answer? Did you saw the following line in the view: `@model SundaysInMonthViewModel`? In my example I passed a single `SundaysInMonthViewModel`. If you need multiple you will have to modify the controller action to pass a list to the view.

Comment: oops yes I did read that part...sorry...Everything is still very new...I am also learning about IEnumerables and selectlistitems still, can I then just add another instance of SundaysInMonthViewModel with SelectedSunday's text and value? thanks

Comment: @charlie_cat, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @charlie_cat, what are you trying to achieve? Please explain what you want to show in your view. 1 DDL? 2 DDLs? What's their content?

Comment: in the view I want a dropdown list that contains the last 2 sundays of previous month and all sundays for this month(exluding future sundays) and with the default the last sunday to the current date thus for this month  we are on the 15th so default one in dropdown will be sunday 12/08/2012..hope it makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @charlie_cat, that's exactly what the code I have shown in my answer does. I will just update it to include your last requirement: `and with the default the last sunday to the current date thus for this month we are on the 15th so default one in dropdown will be sunday 12/08/2012.`. But other then preselecting a default value in the dropdown you could already try to put this into action.

Comment: @charlie_cat, I have updated my answer to illustrate how you could select the last Sunday prior to the current date and use this value to preselect the corresponding element in the dropdown.